# Ant Design: Validating form fields w/custom validators

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I'd like to use [notifications](https://ant.design/components/notification/) to push form feedback, instead of the inline messaging. e.g.

```
<Form.Item label="Name">
  {getFieldDecorator("name", {
    rules: [
      {
        validator(rule, value, callback) {
          if (!value) {
            callback("Enter Your Name");

            // I'd like to use this instead:
            // notification.open({
            //   message: "Enter Your Name",
            //   description:
            //     'This is the content of the notification.',
            // })
          }

          callback();
        }
      }
    ]
  })(<Name />)}
</Form.Item>;
```

Is is possible to validate form fields and maintain the visual feedback (i.e. things like the `border-color` change), without the inline messaging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as you showed in your code and use css to hide error messages.

```
display: none
```

Comment: So obvious. I'm ashamed it wasn't something I considered beforehand.

Comment: `display: none` solves my immediate problem but breaks the layout. `visibility: hidden` is a better solution but I'm not fond of either. Will mark yours as the selected answer, until a better one is offered.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw custom error message using **this.props.form.setFields**

```
this.props.form.setFields({
  user: {
    value: values.user,
    errors: [new Error('forbid ha')],
  },
});
```

[Reference for form.setFields](https://github.com/react-component/form/blob/3b9959b57ab30b41d8890ff30c79a7e7c383cad3/examples/server-validate.js#L74-L79)